# Using sIFR with Lightview

Tags: sifr, wmode

I have problem with sIFRs opacity. after I've installed Lightview I have something like that: !

http://img267.imageshack.us/img267/3525/31troen.jpg
(I can't post images because of spam prevention mechanism ;) )

I've tried to add wmode: 'transparent', but it still does not work.
Replacement call:

```
sIFR.replaceElement("h2", named({sFlashSrc: "<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/candara.swf", wmode: 'transparent', sColor: "#000", sCase: "upper"}));
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The argument in sIFR 2 is `sWmode`, but you really should be using sIFR 3 anyway.